# Can't have persistent Google authentication (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-authentication

I'm trying to have a persistent Google authentication with Firebase. I can log in successfully but the session does not persist if I reload the page.

Here's my code:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
.then(function()
{
    let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(function (result)
    {
        //Save auth data
    });
})
.catch(function(error)
{
    console.error(error);
});
```

This is basically what's written in the docs and should be pretty straightforward. I really don't know what I'm missing.

Also, I don't know what's supposed to happen when the session is permanent, is it just going to authenticate silently or is it going to open the popup, authenticate and then close the popup automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign-in state is automatically persisted to local storage in your browser, and restored when the page/app reloads. To detect changes in authentication state, use an `onAuthStateChanged` listener as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in.
>   } else {
>     // No user is signed in.
>   }
> });
> ```

This listener will fire both when the user actively signs in (i.e. when the call to `signInWithPopup` completes), *and* when the user sign-in state is restored after reloading the app/page.